# Add Google Map to my Google Calendar

Tags: google, google-calendar, google-maps

Ok. So, I have a saved map of my plans for Saturday on it. It's in "My Maps" on Google maps.

Is there a way to link that map (as in attach it to the calendar event, not just paste a link in the details) to the calendar event I have for Saturday in my Google Calendar?

I don't think it's possible, but I figured I'd ask before requesting a feature from Google.

:)

**Update:**

I have found this [Link](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Calendar/thread?tid=3c67043bc5612d12&hl=en) on the Google help forums. From the looks of the date and response on that thread, my outlook is not looking good...

Comment: I just don't think there's enough use cases. It's like Gmail and the selection checkbox.

Comment: Really? I feel like I would use this feature all the time, but I guess Google needs more than just me to use a feature for them to write it. :)

Comment: You can do this with the Google Maps iPhone app, But not on the desktop AFAIK

Answer (score 2):

Per [this Google Calendar help link](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37114) there is at least a way to link a *map location* to an event, though it is not exactly what you want to do, it's close.

> When you fill in the "Where" field on the "Create Event" page, Google Calendar will create a link to a Google Map search result. To ensure an accurate result, please enter a full address, including city and state.
>
> **Note: The "map" link won't appear until you save the event.**

I tested this and it works -- you must enter a mappable address in the location field, then *after you save the map*, a map link will appear on the event:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest:

Make a google map and include a link to it in your description of the event

Describe the location of your event by a name and GPS coordinates e.g.

Miller Room 221 Rockefeller Bldg. Case Western Reserve University @41.503512,-81.6076